# I want to know how to quit the truffle console?

Tags: truffle

just like the question!! I always kill the progress by kill the main shell. I want to change this way.

Answer (score 25):

The command ".exit" also will exit the console.

Answer (score 14):

pressing `ctrl+d` will exit the console.

Answer (score 1):

press ctrl+c
This will also exit the console.

Answer (score 1):

Typing `exit` is ok. No need to kill the terminal.